# Run properly an executable from unity project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, executable

I want to create two buttons in Unity3d. The first one should record, which calls an executable. The second one shoud be a button stop which should return and stop the executable. I have created a simple sample project in Unity and I added an OnGUI() function. I added the two buttons RECORD and STOP. My code is the following:

```
void OnGUI(){

     if (GUI.Button (new Rect (150,250, 100, 50), "RECORD")) {
         System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("D:\\Debug\\exec.exe D:\\ data\\ afds afd");
     }

     if (GUI.Button (new Rect (270,250, 100, 50), "STOP")) {
         ...
     }
 }
```

My first question is about the Process.Start. When I tried from command prompt to run the command from the windows console it works properly. However from the Unity I got the message:

> Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Blockquote

How can I resolve that issue? What should I add in the stop button functionality in order to stop the execution of the .exe file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems quite clear. The file can't be found. The URL doesn't seem correct at all. "D:\Debug\exec.exe D:\ data\ afds afd"
The first part seems alright, but what are you trying to achieve with the "D:\ data\ afds afd" part?

Comment: Is the arguments of the executable. I am not sure if the write way to add them in process. Is how I do it in win32 console.

Comment: Try just putting "D:\Debug\exec.exe" instead of "D:\\Debug\\exec.exe D:\\ data\\ afds afd"

Comment: I tried all the combinations and I got the same error.

Comment: So at what path is your program actually located? Try finding it trough file explorer instead of the command line.

Comment: The exec.exe and the unity project is at different locations. I am not sure what you suggested.

Comment: Yes, but where is the file in your computer? Try checking if there actually is a Debug file in your D: and if the program is actually there.

Comment: I have tried the command suggested in the terminal and it actually worked fine. It run the exe properly with the argumetns.

Comment: Is the "D:\\ data\\ afds afd" part an argument? Because then you'd just have to change it to System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("D:\\Debug\\exec.exe", "D:\\ data\\ afds afd");

Comment: No they are 4 different arguments. Basically this might be my problem. Maybe i do not call properly the exe with the 4 argumetns.

Comment: Chill, you didn't specify that in your question. In that case maybe `string[] args = { "D:\\", "data\\", "afds", "afd" };
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("D:\\Debug\\exec.exe", String.Join(" ", args));` works?

Comment: Hm one last question can I close that executable from the STOP button? The same executable.

Comment: First define the process, like `System.Diagnostics.Process myProcess = new  System.Diagnostics.Process();` then start it like `myProcess.StartInfo.Filename "D:\\Debug\\exec.exe"; myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = args; myProcess.Start();` and stop it like `myProcess.Kill();`